# laravel when I use find I am getting this error: Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\ImageManager::find()

Tags: php, laravel

I am accessing the images through a post relationship in blade.  I want to delete a specific image through the loop I already have. And I am able to get the specific image to the function **destroyImg**.  But I am failing to delete it in **destroyImg**.

When I try to find it first I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Intervention\Image\ImageManager::find()
```

When I kill and dump image by id I can see the specific image. For example:

```
{
  "id": 79,
  "post_id": 31,
  "image": "1596537701-116796500_331884521301081_8587878113120337546_n.jpg",
  "created_at": "2020-08-04T10:41:41.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2020-08-04T10:41:41.000000Z"
}
```

### blade file

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
  @for($i=0;  $i< count($image = $post->images()->get()); $i++)
      //loop has some own operations here


     <form action="/img/delete/{{$image[$i]  }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
   </form>
 @endforeach
```

### postcontroller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\User;
use App\Post;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 public function destroyImg($id)
{
  dd($id);
  $try = Image::find($id);
 
   //$id->delete();
  $user = Auth::guard('web')->id();
  ($user);
  
  return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);
}
```

Comment: what is the full path for Image mode?

Comment: Could you add all the class imports of this controller to your question.

Comment: Intervention/Image doesn't have a find() function. These are the possibilities: http://image.intervention.io/
As a matter of fact, deleting an image has nothing to do with the Intervention package. You'll find the answer here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem

Comment: "image mode?"  the images are stored in public/images. if thats what you asking

Comment: @Remul class imports added

Answer (score 0):

Your `dd()` statement seems to be showing you a string which contains a json representation of the image you wish to delete. You are putting this string into a variable called $id.  $id is likely intended to be an integer?

You should adjust your form to only send the id. It's not completely clear what form that is in, but likely one of these will work:

```
<form action="/img/delete/{{$image[$i]['id'] }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

or

```
 <form action="/img/delete/{{$image[$i]->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

If neither of those resolve the problem, what does the updated output of the `dd()` statement look like with those in place?

Comment: i can get the id value when i use  {{$image[$i]->id }} but still can't go through finding the image  to delete

Comment: thanks for your contribution you helped me get there

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are importing `Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` which does not have a find method, I assume you actually want to call `find` on your `App\Image` model.

Change the following:

```
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image as ImageManager;
use App\Image;
```

Afterwards update all calls to `Image::` that should call `Intervention\Image\Facades\Image` to `ImageManager::`

Answer (score 0):

With the form changed from `{{$image[$i]['id'] }}` to `{{$image[$i]->id }}` I manged to use  find with the image model by passing the model in the **destroyImg** function.

**Note: the image model is images**

### postcontroller

```
 use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
 use App\images;

 public function destroyImg(images $images, $id)
 {
    
    $try = images::find($id); 
    $try->delete();
    
    
    $user = Auth::guard('web')->id(); 
    return redirect()->route('home',['user'=>$user]);
 }
```